# Spring boot server.port not picked up in unit test

Tags: spring, configuration

Spring Boot ::  v2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT
spring-core ::  v5.0.1.RELEASE

I have an application.properties file in my src/main/resources folder that is part of my classpath.

In that file is server.port

In my Configuration class I have :

```
 @Value("${server.port}")
 private String localServerPort;
```

and a bean that uses it:

```
@Bean
public InetSocketAddress tcpSocketAddress() {
  return new InetSocketAddress(Integer.parseInt(this.localServerPort));
}
```

The server.port is not retrieved from the application.properties file when the tcpSocketAddress bean is called, it is -1 at that point.

I have tried a number of different annotations and methods short of reading the file in manually which I think defeats the point.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

full configuration:

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("application.properties")
public class ChronosConfiguration {

  final Logger log = Loggers.getLogger(ChronosConfiguration.class);

  @Value("${server.port}")
  private String localServerPort;

  @Bean
  public CountDownLatch latch() {
    return new CountDownLatch(10);
  }

  @Bean
  public InetSocketAddress tcpSocketAddress() {
    return new InetSocketAddress(Integer.parseInt(this.localServerPort));
  }

}
```

Comment: you don't need this `@PropertySource("application.properties")`. It should work none the less. application.properties is under resources folder right?

Comment: This will only set the value if it is actually set/overrriden somewhere. If you run with the defaults there is no value for `server.port`.

Comment: pvpkiran, yes definitely in the resources folder.

Comment: hmmm, if I do not assume that the property is carried over from the application.properties, and instead use the autowired environment; environment.getProperty("server.port") then I have the same problem.

Seems that I will have to manually load the properties from a yml file or something.

Comment: @PhillipGibb i'm not sure that it will work for you, but take a look https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-discover-the-http-port-at-runtime

Comment: @varren thanks, that is exactly was I was looking for, thanks.